# Laravel update Validator

Tags: php, laravel

How could I use a update and create validator in once? Right now a user must have a unique e-mail address. But when I update it throws an error that it already exists.

What could I do?

```
  $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'RoleId'            => 'required|numeric',
            'DepartmentId'      => 'required|numeric|max:10',
            'FirstName'         => 'required|string|max:50',
            'LastName'          => 'required|string|max:50',
            'email'             => 'required|email|unique:employee|max:50',
            'Gender'            => 'required|numeric|max:1',
            'password'          => 'required|max:50',
            'Address'           => 'required|string|max:50',
            'Zip'               => 'required|string|max:50',
            'City'              => 'required|string|max:50',
            'BirthDate'         => 'required:date|max:10',
            'StartDate'         => 'required:date|max:10',
            'EndDate'           => 'required:date|max:10',
            'Suspended'         => 'required:numeric:max:1'
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

First off I'm assuming you are on Laravel 5. If not then this might not apply. But you can specify you want to ignore a row on the unique validation:

```
'email' => 'required|email|max:50|unique:employee,email,' . $input->id,
```

So you can either check before and adjust the validator string or you can use the `sometimes` option. You will just need to create a hidden field or something that either passes the value of `$model->id`.

```
<input type='hidden' value='{{$model->id}}' name='id' />
```

Option 1

```
$email_validator = "unique:employee,email";
if($request->input('id',0) > 0) {
    $email_validator .= "," . $request->input('id');
}
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    ...
    'email' => 'required|email|max:50|' . $email_validator,
    ...
]);
```

Option 2

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    ...
    'email' => 'required|email|max:50',
    ...
]);
$validator->sometimes('email','unique:employee,email,' . $request->input('id'),function($input){
    return $input->id > 0;
});
$validator->sometimes('email','unique:employee',function($input){
    return $input->id == 0;
});
```